# How does one debug an error that only appears in deployed build and not in local?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

I have built a React app (using CRA) and deployed to Netlify. Runs without error on local development server. When the same repo is pushed to remote and is running on Netlify, it is throwing the following error, which is related to react-pdf/renderer. Since I **can't reproduce the error locally** with the same repo, I'm not sure how to go about debugging it...But clearly something is different between the local build and the deployed build.

```
Error: unsupported number: -Infinity
    number pdfkit.browser.es.js:273
    p pdfkit.browser.es.js:1866
    transform pdfkit.browser.es.js:1865
    translate pdfkit.browser.es.js:1871
    y renderText.js:233
    d _curryN.js:34
    f _arity.js:10
    jt cond.js:42
    f _arity.js:10
    Ke _pipe.js:3
react_devtools_backend.js:4061:25
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you checked the logs? on Netlify

Comment: Few options: 1. deploy a non minified version and then look at the stack trace 2. generate sourcemap 3. put a debugger on the live code and analyze the scope value and stack trace.